# CSS div overflow property problems

Tags: css, html, scroll, overflow

I've got a div that has many listitems in a verticle rows (over 200).  Depending on the screen resolution the container div should resize to fit the screen and create a vertical scroll bar and horizontal scroll bar for side scrolling - however; using overflow:auto or even overflow:scroll the list items are not cut to fit within the container div and a horizontal scroll bar is not added.  So I have a container that is roughly 700px in width and listitems that are roughly 1000px wide and these list items are hanging over the edge of my container (on the right side) by 300px.  What can I do to fix this?..here is my CSS for the container...

```
#report-box #report-text{
   position:relative;
   height:96%;
   width:1200px;
   overflow:auto;
   font-size:12px;
   color:#000;
   margin:0px 0 0 0;
   }
```

My listitems are styled in my HTML as follows:

```
        <li class='_1' style='width:100%; float:left; position:relative;'>SOMEDATA</li>
```

Comment: I need more information on how you're rendering those elements.  Are they in block or inline tags?  Are they just lumped together?  What is the styling on them?

Comment: @Greelmo - your right, I forgot that part - I've now added it to my OP..thanks

Comment: Do you have a demo page you can link to? Perhaps using something like http://jsbin.com so that we can see the rendered page, and perhaps suggest workarounds if not solutions?

Comment: @ricebowl - sorry thats not going to work - I'm rendering sensitive data that cannot be displayed outside our firewall.  Plus, I'm coding in Visual Fox Pro9 and using FoxWeb to render the webpages therefore recoding the entire application would be an extensive project.

Comment: Have you checked to see if you have any styles over-riding other styles? Firebug for Firefox will help you see this.

Comment: @tybro - I would assume from your question that you don't see a problem with the code above...? (I'm checking with firebug now)

Comment: @tybro - I've checked my firebug extensively with no luck.  It seems there are no over-riding styles.

Comment: Based on info given, I don't see where the problem is coming from. A guess would be to try changing the css "display" property on the list items. I know you have sensitive data, but we could best help with a complete example/code to view. Maybe you can make a non-sensitive version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what the problem was but instead of forcing that to work I made an additional container inside of the original container and specified overflow:auto to that and somehow it is now working.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably set a max-height on the container.